# Test the convergence of series $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln n)^{100}}{n}\sin{\frac{\pi n}{4}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have some difficulty with the following exercise:

Test the convergence of series $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln n)^{100}}{n}\sin{\dfrac{\pi n}{4}}$

I think we can use Drichlet or Albel theorem. I tried but I didn't found the way, transfomation to make $\sum \sin{\dfrac{\pi n}{4}}$ convergence or bounded, so it seem that we can't use those theorem.

I don't have any ideas to deal with this problem. Can anyone help me or give me a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let consider

$$\sum_{1}^{2N} \frac{(\ln n)^{100}}{n}\sin{\dfrac{\pi n}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt 2}2\sum_{1}^{N} (-1)^{N+1}\left(\frac{(\ln (2n-1))^{100}}{2n-1}+\frac{(\ln (2n))^{100}}{2n}\right)$$

then take the limit as $N\to \infty$ and show that the latter converges by alternating series test.

Answer (score 2):

Dirichlet's test is enough. The sequence given by $\sin\frac{\pi n}{4}$ has bounded partial sums and $\frac{(\log n)^{100}}{n}$ is eventually decreasing to zero, so the series is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \neq 2k\pi$ you have

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \sin kx = \frac{\sin \frac{(n+1)x}{2}\sin \frac{nx}{2}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}$$

Hence

$$\left\vert\sum_{k=0}^n \sin k \frac{\pi}{4}\right\vert = \left\vert\frac{\sin \frac{(n+1)\pi}{8}\sin \frac{n\pi}{8}}{\sin \frac{\pi}{8}}\right\vert \le \frac{1}{\sin \frac{\pi}{8}}.$$

Based on that you can apply Dirichlet test.